# Issue with PDF to .img conversion using GhostScript

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

We have a process that converts PDF's to .img files.  It all works fine, but when a PDF is bad (bad meaning I can't open the PDF using PDFreader or chrome), this process is not failing as it should, but simply returns a return code of Zero (and also does not create any .img files). This is a C# code.

```
int result = InitAPI(gsInstancePtr, args.Length, args);
if (result < 0) {bSuccess = false; }
```

Definition of InitAPI that I am using (for your reference):

```
[DllImport("gsdll32.dll", EntryPoint = "gsapi_init_with_args")]
private static extern int InitAPI(IntPtr instance, int argc, string[] argv);
```

My question is:

1. Does anyone know how can I know that the conversion failed / PDF is bad?
2. Do you know when trying to convert a PDF in to individual .img files (I mean each PDF page is a separate .img file), if Ghostscripts converts one page at a time and fails when it tries to convert a bad page (the previous pages are already converted to .img files and saved to disk) or it is all or nothing (is success only if it is able to convert all pages fails otherwise)?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the problem with the PDF file is, its not really possible to tell very much.

For what its worth, Ghostscript will render each page in turn, so if there is a problem with a specific page (as opposed to the entire file) then all the pages to that point will be rendered to a file. Note that Ghostscript will not generally exit when it encounters a broken PDF file (unless you set -dPDFSTOPONERROR) but may produce blank or partial pages.

I don't know of a way to get Ghostscript to fail to produce an output file, and yet not emit an error.

I'd need to see an example of such a file to comment further, the version of Ghostscript being used and the command line (the args since you are linking to the DLL).